# Cannot print when td content is too large while printing

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, tr

```
<tr>       
   <td>
     <table> 
        <tr>
          <td>
              <div>
                 lot of data
              </div>
          </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
 </td>
```

I can print properly in a4 or others. However, a6 paper size preview is loading error on chrome. Works fine in Microsoft Edge.Why?

Answer (score 1):

Use WordWrap

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="word-wrap: break-word">
       lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. I've been dealing with this error for days. It happened after version 108 of Chrome. And it only does it in A6 size

Comment: @BüşraGüler Kindly Go through this documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout#try_it

Comment: I checked, normally there is no problem, just because there is an error while printing @@media print{ table-layout : fixed; }ve table-layout :auto;  I wrote it as .but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<table style="width:50%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <th>data</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="word-break: break-word;">
                    lot of lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data lot of data
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: So I can choose what I want to print in my application. That's why it gives an error when I choose the one with more content. I did what you said. It didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

It prints when I do it like this. But I guess it doesn't fit the table structure.

```
<tr>       
   <td>
     <table> 
        <tr>
          <td>
              <div>
                <tr>
                    data
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  lot of data
                </tr>
              </div>
          </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
 </td>
```